# Proper way to list all data that have active field in django

Tags: python, django

Sorry about the improper question,but couldn't think how to write better one. Here is the problem, 
i got a model in django that is a list of service(basically contains name and details field) and another table serviceManager that has foreign key to user and service as two fields. Now when a user wants to populate his active services, i make a query to populate all his services from serviceManager. Now the issue is that i want to display all services and mark active field only in front of row that are active.

So suppose that there are 3 service and user is using 2 out of them, then i want all three listed but active in front of two that he is using.

What i am looking for is the best way to do the same. I want to avoid looping in django because of size of dataset.

addition of model codes

```
class ServiceDetails(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=128, unique=True)
    about = models.CharField(max_length=500, unique=True)
    STATUS_ACTIVATED = 0
    STATUS_DEACTIVATED = 1
    STATUS_UNAVAILABLE = 2
    STATUS_CHOICES = [(STATUS_ACTIVATED,'Active'),(STATUS_DEACTIVATED, 'Down'),(STATUS_UNAVAILABLE, 'Unavailable')]
    status = models.IntegerField(choices = STATUS_CHOICES,default = 1)
    serviceSlug = models.SlugField(max_length=150,default="")

    def __unicode__(self):
        return self.name

class serviceManager(models.Model):
    user = models.ForeignKey(settings.AUTH_USER_MODEL)
    startup = models.ForeignKey(startup)
    services = models.ForeignKey(ServiceDetails)
    created = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
```

I get list of active service from serviceManager but i need to populate complete ServiceDetails with those active in service manager marked in html

Comment: Could you add the models as well.

Comment: @AKS have a look now

Comment: It seems that for all the users you want to list all the services here but with the active/inactive status.

Comment: @AKS please disregard the status in models,not the same. ServiceDetails is just a directory of services. ServiceManager is a list that contains foreign key to user and service. Now i filter all service active for a user from  `serviceManager` and then list all service from ServiceDetails. What i need to do is show all objects in ServiceDetails but if it is active from user as seen from serviceManager, mark it as active in UI